Changing matplotlib collection segment
I'm using matplotlib's collection, and in some cases I'd like to change the value of segment.
However, I don't know how to change the segment of the collection.
That's why I'm removing the existing collection and then creating and adding a new collection.
# the way i use it now
new_collections = {collection list}
for i in ax.collections: i.remove()
for i in new_collections: ax.add_collection(i)
ax.figure.canvas.draw()

I think it would be faster if I could only change segments of an existing collection rather than removing the existing collection and adding a new one.
Is this possible?

What do you want to change exactly? is it for all the lines or only some of them?

exactly, i want both. @rehaqds

What type of collection are you using? Matplotlib has many and the way they can be updated varies https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html

I'm using linecollection and polycollection. @RuthC

LineCollection has a set_segments method.  PolyCollection has set_verts and set_sizes.
